# Почему php-fpm не записывает файл?

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm

На nginx поставил php-fpm он работает, но он не создаёт файл.

Мой файл `/var/www/html/post1.php`

```
<?php
$fh = fopen("/home/user/TestPost.txt", "a+");
fwrite($fh, var_dump($_POST));
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Я перезапускаю nginx перезапускаю php7.4-fpm и захожу на сервер через браузер и в итоге ответ на странице

```
array(0) { }
```

не понимаю почему вообще он выводиться если должен по идее быть записан в файл

Затем проверяю `/home/user/` и вижу что файла `TestPost.txt` там нет. Я думал может быть файлу `post1.php` нужны права так дал ему админа

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 105 Jan 30 16:10 post1.php
```

В чём проблема? php-fpm вообще не может создавать файлы? или нужно что-то в конфиге nginx'a прописать?

Comment: `var_dump` данные выводит в стандартный вывод, коим является ваш хттп ответ, а не в возвращает строку для записи.

Comment: `print_r($_POST, true)` попробуйте, или через буферизацию.

Comment: @teran Попробовал вывод в браузере пропал но файл всё так-же не записался. Так-же попробовал просто строку записать `fwrite($fh, "hello")` но так-же файл не создался.

Comment: попробуйте в `/var/www` у себя сначала где нить записать.

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем разобрался в логах nginx'a `/var/log/nginx/error.log` была ошибка `permission denied` и я разобрался что в php-fpm в файле пула был задан пользователь и группа www-data а у него не было прав на запись даже в `/home/user`

Comment: так у вас вроде ж права 777 стояли

Comment: @teran Я дал 777 файлу `post1.php`  но запись в `/home/user/` была только для владельца. Так что либо надо было в файле пула `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` выставлять user вместо www-data либо давать всем права на запись в `/home/user/`

Comment: права надо выставлять на файл, которые вы записываете, а не которой пишет. Надо было вашему txt файлу установить группу `chown username:www-data` и дать права на запись`chmod g+w`.

Comment: хорошо, что почитали логи. Не надо хотеть писать, читать или выполнять файлы из/в произвольные каталоги.  И давать всем права на запись в любой /home/* не нужно.